# Python fmin too slow

Tags: python, optimization, numpy, scipy

i have a 3x2000 numpy array in x_data and a 1x2000 numpy array in y_data which i pass to this function regress to give me a regression line.  it works fine.  the problem is that i am trying to do some backtesting and to test 1000 situations i have to regress 1000 times and it will take me about 5 minutes to run this.

i tried standardizing the variables it didn't seem to make it faster.

i also briefly tried fmin_powell and fmin_bfgs which seemed to break it.

any ideas? thanks!

```
def regress(x_data, y_data, fg_spread, fg_line):

    theta = np.matrix(np.ones((1,x_data.shape[0]))*.11)
    hyp = lambda theta, x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(theta*x)))
    cost_hyp = lambda theta, x, y: ((np.multiply(-y,np.log10(hyp(theta,x)))) - \
                            (np.multiply((1-y),(np.log10(1-hyp(theta, x)))))).sum()

    theta = scipy.optimize.fmin(cost_hyp, theta, args=(x_data,y_data), xtol=.00001, disp=0)

    return hyp(np.matrix(theta),np.matrix([1,fg_spread, fg_line]).reshape(3,1))
```

Comment: pay attention when adding and save min at that point?

Comment: Five minutes doesn't have to be long; that's really relative (and just the time you need to get a cup of coffee). Also, you set xtol a factor 10 lower; that may slow things down. And what does 'break it' mean in this context? Since I guess these may be slightly faster.

Comment: Joran, could you please explain what you mean more? thanks

Comment: Evert, I use different values of theta but when i do fmin_bfgs I get this error message 

Warning (from warnings module):
  File "C:\Python27\ncaalogistic.py", line 80
    (np.multiply((1-y),(np.log10(1-hyp(theta, x)))))).sum()
RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply

Answer (score 2):

Use [numexpr](http://code.google.com/p/numexpr/) to make your hyp and cost_hyp computatation to evaluate faster. fmin family of functions compute those functions numerous times for different entries. So any gain to those functions are directly reported in the minimization.

So for instance you would replace:

```
hyp = lambda theta, x: 1 / (1 + np.exp(-(theta*x)))
```

by:

```
hyp = lambda theta, x: numexpr.evaluate("1 / (1 + exp(-(theta*x)))")
```

Numexpr is meant to work with numpy array.

Comment: Nicolas, I looked into this but I am not sure how I can use numexpr here.  I see two problems.  First numexpr seems to be for simple arithmetic, so I am not sure how I can use it here with this linear algebra and do matrix multiplication?

Second, I am not sure what you mean by "fasten your hyp and cost_hyp", I am kind of new to these topics so if you could please give me a few more words of explanation.  thanks!